# Endnote is duplicated in all the empty istances

Tags: footnotes, minipage, endnotes

I was [trying to place multiple footnotes level inside a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668992/many-footnotes-type-rendering-inside-the-minipage-not-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) I came up with a solution using endnotes which allows me two footnotes level in a minipage. However, when I have some unexpected behaviour, the endnote of one minipage is copied on the others.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\renewcommand*{\enoteheading}{}

\newcommand{\ent}[3]{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vspace{5pt}
\marginnote{#1}
\textit{#2}\\      
\onehalfspacing
#3
\vspace{5pt}
\setcounter{endnote}{0}
\theendnotes
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
This is a test for the rest of the document:\\
\ent{III 250-1}{ sdfg sdfg sdfgs rwr wrt.}{wertwertt\footnote{footnote A } \footnote{footnote B)}}
\ent{III 252}{\dots Cyrene \dots}{Cyrene condita est a Theraeis\footnote{footnote C }. some text goes here. \endnote{The only endnote is dublicated}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this happens with `endnotes`, but would you be open to using some other end notes package?

Comment: @gusbrs thanks for your comment! Yes, at the moment I have solved the issue with an if statement, but there are some features that I would like to implement such as inline footnotes, that I am not able to achieve with endnotes so I gladly switch to another package

Comment: Well, the different end notes packages are quite similar in basic structure. I just happened to test it with `postnotes` and your MWE worked. I assume it may just as well work with `enotez` too. I have no idea if they would grant the other features you are intending, the one you are aiming here is already clearly an abuse of end notes (may work or not, but it is not the intended use). Anyway, since you already got the original question working, no need for an answer just changing the package.

Comment: I think that an answer with a working example is always a good reference. So if you want to post one I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Agreed, I just said that because, since you found a solution with an if statement, the more meaningful thing here would be for you to self answer, which would fit more precisely in the framework of the original question. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using an if statement `\if\theendnote0` if the number of endnotes is zero do not print the endnotes:

```
\newcommand{\ent}[3]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\marginnote{#1}
\textit{#2}\\      
#3
\if\theendnote0
\else
\setcounter{endnote}{0}
\theendnotes
\fi
\end{minipage}
}}
```